# Save Docusign Document as Template through API

Tags: docusignapi

The docusign website allows for me to save a document as a template, but I have not been able to find a way to do this programmatically through the API. Is there a simple way to save a document as a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Template via the API by issuing this request:

`POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates`

The [API documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/create/) contains details about this operation.

---

### UPDATE

Do I understand correctly that your goal is to create a Template that's based upon an existing DocuSign Document, i.e., to mimic the following functionality in the DocuSign web UI?

[image: Save As]

If that's the case, then I'm not aware of any single API call that can do this. Instead, I believe you'll need to issue a series of API calls, to retrieve info about the existing Document(s) and then create the new Template using that info:

1) Get information about the existing DocuSign Document (envelope): `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}` ([docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/))

- This operation returns recipient info (including tabs for each recipient) as well as envelope data like email subject, email body, reminders, etc. It also returns a `documentsUri` property that you can use to get the document(s) that belong to the envelope.

2) Get the list of document(s) that the envelope contains by issuing a GET request to the URI specified by the `documentsUri` from the prior response. ([docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/))

- This operation returns information about each document in the specified envelope, but does not return document contents.

3) For each document listed in the prior API response, issue a GET request to the URI specified by the `uri` property for the document. ([docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/))

4) Finally, create a new Template using the data that you received in response to the previous API requests: `POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates` ([docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/create/))

**Note**: As a final note -- if you're using one of the DocuSign SDKs, it's possible that there might be a function that you can call to implement this scenario, without having to piece together all of these API calls yourself. I'm not familiar enough with the SDKs to say whether or not they provide this type of functionality, but it'd be worth checking for, if you're using an SDK.

Comment: thanks!, but is there a way to save an already created docusign document as a template? this option is offered through the website but haven't been able to find a method for it in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ryan.  I've updated my answer to add additional info.

Comment: @RyanWelish -- if my answer sufficiently addressed your question, can you please mark it as an "accepted" answer? Doing so will allow others to potentially benefit from the info in the future. Thanks!